# Books for learning signals and systems?

Tags: reference-request, books

Please recommend books for learning/studying signals and systems
I know about oppenhiem,please write about other books that are easy to understand

Comment: hi abtj, this is a question for opinions: "Easy" is a subjective term. It's very welcome to ask for references, but your question needs to be far more specific and actually describe what you need, instead of just "easy to understand" (personally, Oppenheim is pretty OK, but that's very subjective; again, this is a place for questions that can have a "right" answer, and your question doesn't allow for that).

Answer (score 3):

[Linear Signals and systems by Lathi](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Systems_and_Signals.html?id=Wh9yswEACAAJ&source=kp_cover)

Check out [MIT lectures of Prof. Oppenheim](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/video-lectures/) too. Those were super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

digital signal processing by sk mitra

Answer (score 0):

Strum and Kirk's [First Principles of Discrete Systems and Digital Signal Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201095181) is very good for beginners, but restricted to discrete time systems, if that's what you're looking for.